# Where to add a do while loop to have the program repeat or terminate?

Tags: java, while-loop, do-while

I'm new to programming, this is my first Java class.
I've gotten a code to calculate temperature from celsius to fahrenheit and vice versa, but I cannot figure out where I should have entered a Do While loop to have the program repeat or terminate.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PracticeTemp {
    private static float f = 0, c = 0;
    private static final Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    private static int converChoice = 1;

    public static void main(String [] args) {
    System.out.println("Press 1 for C->F or 2 for F->C 3 to Quit");
    converChoice = scan.nextInt();

    if (converChoice == 1) 
        convertCtoFAndPrint();
    else if
    (converChoice == 2) 
        convertFtoCAndPrint();
    else if
    (converChoice == 3)
    System.out.println("The program will now terminate");
    System.exit(0);

    }

    public static void convertFtoCAndPrint() {
    System.out.println("Please enter degrees F");
    f = scan.nextFloat();

    c = (5* (f - 32)) / 9f;

    System.out.println(f + " degrees F is " + c + " degrees C.");
    }

     public static void convertCtoFAndPrint() {
    System.out.println("Please enter degrees C");
    c = scan.nextFloat();

    f = (9 * c + 160) / 5f;

    System.out.println(c + " degrees C is " + f + " degrees F.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Try putting it around the code to repeat. Also try a [mcve]. In other words, play around with it using less code

Comment: If you know how your code works and what you want your code to do, you should be able to figure out which code should repeat, which is what you should surround with do-while. If you don't know how your code works or what you want your code to do, you're asking the wrong question to the wrong people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the program to repeat and get input from the console you have to include a

```
while(true){
    //this is an infinite loop
}
```

in the main function where the user inputs data:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
        while(true) { //this in an infinite loop
            System.out.println("Press 1 for C->F or 2 for F->C 3 to Quit");
            converChoice = scan.nextInt();

            if (converChoice == 1)
                convertCtoFAndPrint();
            else if (converChoice == 2)
                convertFtoCAndPrint();
            else if (converChoice == 3) {
                System.out.println("The program will now terminate");
                System.exit(0);//this stops the program
            }
        }
    }
```

Or you can add:

```
do{

}while(converChoice!=3);
```

> This repeats as long as convertChoice (user input) is not equal to 3

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
        do {
            System.out.println("Press 1 for C->F or 2 for F->C 3 to Quit");
            converChoice = scan.nextInt();

            if (converChoice == 1)
                convertCtoFAndPrint();
            else if (converChoice == 2)
                convertFtoCAndPrint();
            else if (converChoice == 3) {
                System.out.println("The program will now terminate");
                // System.exit(0); is no longer needed since the program exists the loop
            }
        } while (converChoice!=3);
    }
```

Comment: I added the do/while example too. His code has more sense using infinite loop because of System.exit(0);

Comment: Well infinite loops should be avoided. Although there is the terminating condition defined inside the loop, it is a bad code practice because one has to read the entire code to determine the stopping condition therefore the loop is unessesarily unclear to the reader. Here, we know the terminating condition and we can use it as the loop condition which makes more sense. If you really want the termination message, or anything else, you can put it under the loop where it will show once the loop stops.

Comment: I totaly agree, that's why I added the do while loop. However I wanted to provide an example for the OP using his code.

Comment: I seem mabe it would be a good idea to mention that in your post though to avoid confusion for the OP and future readers :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could put it arround the code inside the main method body such that every time the first execution of the program is complete, it repeats by showing the "Press 1 ..." message, re-accepting input and so on.

```
public static void main(String[] argz){
   do{
      //Do stuff.
   }while(condition);
}
```

In your case, the condition should be something along the lines of `converChoice != 3` which will essentially stop when `converChoice` is equal to 3.